# How should I know the dependency module name of a module?

Tags: angularjs, bower

I install some Angular modules with bower.

Is there a way of finding easily the corresponding module name to add it in the Angular app dependencies?

---

**Example**

1. `bower install angular-drag-and-drop-lists --save`
2. Look for the module dependency name (I assume some Angular modules have more than one module) in the readme/docs/sources: `dndLists`
3. Add `'dndLists'` to the dependencies

Comment: it's usually the name of the module in the js file of the component you download for example : angular.module('angular-flot', []) .. sometimes it's the directive: or service angular.module('ngProgress.provider', ['ngProgress.directive'])
    .service('ngProgress', function () ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they follow the typical angular naming convention it might be easy to guess:

The first part of the file should be the company name unabbreviated, and snake case. The second part of the file should be the module description, also snake case.  When the company name is abbreviated, you get the namespace. When you combine the namespace and the module description, in camel case, you get the module name.

It should be clear from examples:

angular-route.js -->

- company = angular
- module description = route
- filename = angular-route.js
- prefix = ng (namespace for angular)
- suffix = route
- module name = ngRoute

angular-animate.js -->

- company = angular
- module description = animate
- filename = angular-animate.js
- prefix = ng (namespace for angular)
- suffix = animate
- module name = ngAnimate

angular-drag-and-drop-lists -->

- company = angular-drag-and-drop
- module description = lists
- filename = angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js
- prefix = dnd (namespace for angular-drag-and-drop)
- suffix = lists
- module name = dndLists

In the above case, they didn't exactly follow naming convention as it may not have been easy to guess angular-drag-and-drop is abbreviated as 'dnd'. But you might find that most angular modules do.

Side note:

UI bootstrap does not follow this convention.

Although if they had, the files and module names might have been:

```
bootstrap-ui.js --> ui
bootstrap-ui-collapse.js --> uiCollapse
bootstrap-ui-accordion.js --> uiAccordion
bootstrap-ui-buttons.js --> uiButtons
etc
```

Personally, I like that module names are easy to guess from their filenames.  For UI Bootstrap, I like the above naming convention better.

Answer (score 0):

**1 :**
Usually angular modules has a readme.md file if it's from github.com. Where they help you to go through adding module to your application.

**2 :**
Second and the best method to open the main .js file and find the main angular.module() name.

**Example**

```
angular.module("ui.bootstrap", ["ui.bootstrap.collapse","ui.bootstrap.accordion","ui.bootstrap.alert","ui.bootstrap.buttons","ui.bootstrap.carousel","ui.bootstrap.dateparser","ui.bootstrap.position","ui.bootstrap.datepicker","ui.bootstrap.dropdown","ui.bootstrap.stackedMap","ui.bootstrap.modal","ui.bootstrap.pagination","ui.bootstrap.tooltip","ui.bootstrap.popover","ui.bootstrap.progressbar","ui.bootstrap.rating","ui.bootstrap.tabs","ui.bootstrap.timepicker","ui.bootstrap.typeahead"]);
```

[ui-bootstrap example](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap-bower/blob/master/ui-bootstrap.js)

Comment: I hoped there was a better way